# Have generative grammarians abandoned the notion of transformations?

Tags: syntax

When I peruse this site and others, I find references to apparent operations that change either one surface structure to another (as with passivization) or a deep structure to a surface structure (as with raising).

Is the notion of transformations still current among generative linguists?

If not, how do generative grammarians generally explain the linguistic data formerly explained by transformations?

If so, where can I find a list of transformations currently acknowledged by generative grammarians?

Also if so, has the number of acknowledged transformations decreased over time?

Comment: Try [this one](http://www.umich.edu/~jlawler/haj/Preliminarybufattenedlistoftransformations.pdf) out and then you tell me.

Comment: That is a fantastic list, and one I've been wanting to see for ages.

Comment: Anyone seriously interested in transformations should consult [Jim McCawley's](http://www.umich.edu/~jlawler/McCawley-Lg.pdf) _The Syntactic Phenomena of English_, as well as [Haj Ross's papers](http://www.umich.edu/~jlawler/haj), and **really** serious syntacticians will appreciate [Squibnet](http://www.umich.edu/~jlawler/haj/Squibnet).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think the notion of transformation still exists for most generative grammarians, although the use of the exact term *transformation* has fallen out of favor. One tends to break transformations down into their component procedures. One acknowledges mechanisms such as *move* or *copy* or *merge* to describe and explain how various grammatical structures are related to and derived from each other. The underlying idea remains the same, however, although the description of the transformations has become much more exact than it was in the early days of Transformational Grammar.